Apache Tomcat as service, wkhtmltopdf and folder permissions
I have an Apache Tomcat server running a webapp that needs to create PDF files using the wkhtmltopdf utility.
The following have been observed :

when tomcat is run from the eclipse environment, the PDF files are properly created
when tomcat is run as service, wkhtmltopdf runs, but error code 255 is returned
the same command line that returns error code 255 is correctly executed from the DOS prompt.

That lead me to suspect a permission problem. So I changed the account under which the Apache Tomcat is executed. The immediate effect is that wkhtmltopdf creates the PDF file correctly.
So the conclusion is that, when run as service using the local system setting, the wkhtmltopdf inherits the security context and cannot access the files, even if the folder has system access set to 'full control'.
Is this assesment correct ?
If yes, how to set permissions so that the wkhtmltopdf get proper access to the folder when executed from the windows service ?
